# Pedal problem, slop, or “float”?

Tags: spd

I’ve got SM51 cleats. I’ve learned (here) that I likely replaced SM56s. I’ve got a lot I could learn but I’m not a newbie. I've got about 8,000 miles on these pedals/cleats/shoes. Maybe only 1500 on the new cleats though. I’m feeling like I’m getting some lateral movement. Not tons. millimeters. Just feels a tad sloppy. No shims under cleats. Pedals are year old and have about 5,000 miles on them. 95% road and 5% gravel. Pedal shafts aren’t showing any perceptible wiggle. Getting in/out slightly harder with newer cleats but that was expected & not problematic.

Am I just being a bike-hypochondriac or is there a potential real issue here?

Comment: How old are the cleats? They do not last forever. Are they visibly worn? Or just replace and see.

Comment: All SM5x cleats have 3° sideways float. (SM51 and SM56) SM56 have a different release behaviour. They release also when the rider lifts the heel.